# Terminal application

Tags: terminal, gnome-terminal, terminal-emulator, gnome-terminator, kitty

I added a padding to my terminal ([kitty](https://sw.kovidgoyal.net/kitty/)) and it looks pretty good, but when I open [vim](https://www.howtoforge.com/vim-basics) or [alsamixer](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/Alsamixer) they look bad with this padding.

So my question is can I, in [kitty](https://sw.kovidgoyal.net/kitty/) or in any other terminal emulator, set padding only when any other application like vim and alsamixer doesn't open in this emulator.

In other words, can I remove padding from the terminal emulator when vim/alsamixer is open in it.

Sorry for my bad English, I hope you can understand me.

This is also my first question here so sorry If I do something bad.

Comment: a screenshot of "good" and a screenshot of "bad" would help

Comment: What "padding" is this please?

Comment: Padding is inner margin.

Comment: Inner in which language? Indo-Europeans would say the inner is the left margin; Arabic and Hebrew users would say the inner is the right margin.

Comment: @K7AAY all the margins left, right, up and down. Have a read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding).

Comment: A better idea would be to teach `vim` and `alsamixer` to use the default bg/fg colors, instead of explicitly making the terminal black or other color. `vim` already does that, in my experience. But then, I'm not using kitty.